# Replacement for TRect and TPoint in Delphi Prism

Tags: .net, types, delphi-prism, win32-process

What do you replace TRect and TPoint with from Delphi Win32 code to Delphi Prism code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options depending of your needs

**using Rectangle and Point from the System.Drawing namespace Since Net 1.0**

TRect -> [`System.Drawing.Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx)

TPoint ->  [`System.Drawing.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx)

**using Rect and Point from the System.Windows namespace Since Net 3.0**

TRect -> [`System.Windows.Rect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx)

TPoint -> [`System.Windows.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx)

Comment: I wish that was an answer to my question, but it doesn't work. It is raising error, "Error (PE9) Unknown identifier System.Windows.TRect" That also goes for Tpoints.

Comment: the name of the structure is `Rect` not TRect. the same goes for Point.

Comment: okay I did make the changes accordingly and still I get the same error.... Are U allowed to do this - method FixRect(var r:System.Windows.Rect); in parameter list. I wish my IDE help worked.

Comment: @digitalanalog, you must add the WindowsBase reference to your project.